# Converting 8kHz mulaw to PCM 16kHz

Tags: node.js, audio, twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-voice

Im trying to receive a conversation streaming from Twilio in 8kHz mulaw and I want to convert it to 16kHz PCM for some processing ( that doesnt support 8kHz mulaw format), I tried this method but without success :
   - convert the string payload to base64 buffer.
   - convert the buffer to Uint8Array with this package: [buffer-to-uint8array](http://github.com/substack/buffer-to-uint8array).
   - convert the Uint8Array to Int16Array with this pacakge: [alawmulaw](https://github.com/rochars/alawmulaw).
   - then use wav library to write the results.
I am still unable to get a valid audio file following this process, Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong ? or guide me to achieve this ?

Comment: I would get this working from the command line first then implement in your code ... either use ffmpeg or sox or the audio workstation called Audacity ... use one of these tools to directly convert a file in 8kHz mulaw  to your  16kHz PCM  ... doing this will confirm your input file is OK and give you a valid output file to later bounce your code's output file against

Comment: i can't use audacity or ffmpeg because i need this in real time, i could convert the file with ffmpeg but doesnt suit my need, so i am looking for a way to do that in realtime ( when receiving the data )

Comment: my above suggestion is not to solve your problem its to make it easier

Comment: Hello , I did try this solution already thank you !

Answer (score 7):

I've had good luck using the WaveFile lib (https://www.npmjs.com/package/wavefile)

```
const wav = new WaveFile();
wav.fromScratch(1, 8000, '8m', Buffer.from(payload, "base64"));
wav.fromMuLaw();
// You can resample.
wav.toSampleRate(16000);
// You can write this straight to a file (will have the headers)
const results = wav.toBuffer();
// Or you can access the samples without the WAV header
const samples = wav.data.samples;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: @SalahEddineBachirCherif  is this solution worked for you?, even I also want to convert ULAW format to WAV

Comment: @u_pendra, havent tried this one, we used another solution, we found a file header that is compatible and we made our converter

Comment: @SalahEddineBachirCherif can you share the solution.

Comment: @u_pendra we started from this solution, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58959534/10794312

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it @SalahEddineBachirCherif