# Convert Twilio Mulaw to 16Khz PCM stream in Node JS

Tags: node.js, twilio

I'm coding a Twilio auto answer bot. I can receive the stream from twilio and get the content using msg.media.payload in the "media" event of the socket. But I cannot convert the base64 mulaw to 16 bit pcm array using NodeJS.

```
function basetoPCM(data){
  console.log(data)
  var blob  = atob(data);   // Base64 string converted to a char array
  console.log("use base64 decoder to decode the Payload received.");
    console.log(blob);

  //use this payload buffer and decode using the G.711 decoder (mulaw to pcm)
  var pcm = alawmulaw.mulaw.decode(blob);
  console.log("getting decode pcm");
  console.log(pcm);
  return pcm;
}
```

But the response it get it just an array with same number:

```
getting decode pcm
Int16Array(160) [
  -32124, -32124, -32124, -32124, -32124, -32124, -32124, ...
```

The function to send audio to the Kaldi transcribe server that I use is:

```
const buffer = e;
      const int16ArrayData = convertFloat32ToInt16(buffer);
      console.log("int16data");
      console.log(int16ArrayData)
      this.ws.send(int16ArrayData.buffer);
```

So my question is how to convert Twilio base64 mulaw to a 16 bit PCM audio buffer. And is there anyway to make Twilio encode in PCM? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I've not used the [alawmulaw library](https://github.com/rochars/alawmulaw) you seem to be trying here, but looking at the docs it appears you might be running the wrong function here. As the live web socket data arrives, I would have thought it was a "sample" rather than a set of samples and that you should try:

```
var pcm = alawmulaw.mulaw.decodeSample(blob);
```

Alternatively, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61381395/28376) my colleague Craig recommended the [WaveFile lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wavefile). Take a look at the answer for some sample code.