# Proccesing audio from twilio media stream using Python

Tags: python, audio, stream, twilio, media

I am streaming call audio to my local server using Twilio Streams.
For reference I used the offical [guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/consume-real-time-media-stream-using-websockets-python-and-flask) from the Twilio Team.

Decoding the audio and saving it to a .wav file works, although when playing back the audio sounds somewhat distored  ("slow-motion" with compression artificats). You can listen to it on [soundcloud here](https://on.soundcloud.com/ipYr). Compared to the [audio recording that twilio provides](https://on.soundcloud.com/iWEv) from the twilio console for the same call, there is a notable difference. Now I would want to get the audio from the stream to sound ideally just as good, as I need to feed it into a custom ML model.

When comparing the above audio files using this code:

```
import pywav
wave_read = pywav.WavRead("filename.wav")
print(wave_read.getparams())
```

We get:

**Twilio Audio:**
{'numchannels': 1, 'samplerate': 8000, 'byterate': 16000, 'bytespersample': 2, 'bitspersample': 16, 'samplelength': 82998, 'audioformat': 'PCM (without compression)'}

**Stream Audio:**
{'numchannels': 1, 'samplerate': 8000, 'byterate': 16000, 'bytespersample': 2, 'bitspersample': 16, 'samplelength': 69120, 'audioformat': 'PCMU (with mu-law compression)'}

I am fairly certain that the problem lies in how I save the decoded bytes from the stream into file.

```
  if data['event'] == "media":
        if not has_seen_media:
            recorded.append(base64.b64decode(data['media']['payload']))
            app.logger.info("Media message: {}".format(message))
            payload = data['media']['payload']
            app.logger.info("Payload is: {}".format(payload))
            chunk = base64.b64decode(payload)
            recorded.append(chunk)
            app.logger.info("That's {} bytes".format(len(chunk)))
            app.logger.info("Additional media messages from WebSocket are being suppressed....")
            has_seen_media = False
    if data['event'] == "closed":
        app.logger.info("Closed Message received: {}".format(message))
        break
    message_count += 1


app.logger.info("Connection closed. Received a total of {} messages".format(message_count))
data_bytes = b''.join(recorded)
wave_write = pywav.WavWrite("Recording.wav", 1,8000,8,7)  # 1 stands for mono channel, 8000 sample rate, 8 bit, 7 stands for MULAW encoding
wave_write.write(data_bytes)
wave_write.close()
```

Note: I have changed the bits from 8 to 16 in the WavWrite function with no difference in audio quality.

I've looked at implementing code snippets from this [previous post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58439005/is-there-any-way-to-save-mulaw-audio-stream-from-twilio-in-a-file). Although without success.

How would you improve the quality of the saved audio file? (ideally in python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what the issue is. In your loop, you add the decoded audio to the array of payloads twice:

```py
recorded.append(base64.b64decode(data['media']['payload'])) # <<< Adding the payload for the first time
app.logger.info("Media message: {}".format(message))
payload = data['media']['payload']
app.logger.info("Payload is: {}".format(payload))
chunk = base64.b64decode(payload)
recorded.append(chunk) # <<< Adding the payload for the second time
```

If you listen to the audio, it is slow because it seems to be repeating each chunk. If you cut one of the lines above I think you will have correct sounding audio.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot, removed the line and the audio sounds perfect now!